# The ratio of two positive real..

Tags: polynomials

The ratio of two positive real numbers is $p + \sqrt {p^2 - q^2} : p- \sqrt {p^2 - q^2}$ then find the ratio of their AM and GM.

My Approach.
Given,
$$\frac {p + \sqrt {p^2 - q^2}}{p - \sqrt {p^2 - q^2}}$$

Let the numbers be $a$ and $b$.

Then $$a=p + \sqrt {p^2-q^2}$$ and $$b=p - \sqrt {p^2-q^2}$$

Please help me to continue from here.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a=k(p+\sqrt{p^2-q^2})$ and $b=k(p-\sqrt{p^2-q^2})$. Their $A.M.=\dfrac{a+b}{2}=\dfrac{2kp}{2}=kp$. For some $k>0$.

$G.M.=\sqrt{ab}=\sqrt{k^2(p^2-(p^2-q^2))}=|kq|$. Thus $\frac{AM}{GM}=\dfrac{p}{|q|}$.

Comment: How is $k$ there?

Comment: If i give you ratio of two numbers you cant uniquely determine them eg 2/3=4/6=...

Comment: Oh.. I am having problem in one co ordinate geometry question. Will you help me?

Comment: Do post it in the site, its a really helpful community you will surely get help..

Comment: I didn't get anything though I tried that question. Then how could I post the question in the site even without showing my attempt?

Comment: You can post by saying that you are having trouble starting with it, they will understand that.

Comment: I have posted at here: math.stackexchange.com/questions/1916248/the-distance-of-a-point-ph-k. Please check once.